# Does NSubstitute support ref parameters?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have the following method signature in my iterface:

```
void SetItem(ref AddressItem item);
```

I do a parameter constraint like this:

```
IAddAddressForm form = Substitute.For<IAddAddressForm>();
AddressItem item = null;
form.SetItem(Arg.Is(item));
```

But that fails because of the ref.  If I take the ref out then it works fine.  But I need to pass by reference here.

Any ideas how to get this?

Side Note: My ultimate goal is to throw an exception in SetItem if the passed in value is null.  If you can help with that then you get extra points!

Comment: I'm really curious as to why you need to use `ref` here. Can you please explain?

Comment: Well, I am making a sample project to train my IT Department on unit testing using NSubstitute and Moles.  As part of this I want to mole Linq-To-SQL.  To do that, I needed to do some updating to an object returned by a Linq-to-sql query.  I found that if I did not pass the object with the `ref` then the update failed (Because it no longer recongnized the object as the one queried.)  This may not be the "best practice" for linq to sql, but I am training unit testing, not Linq.

Comment: You can see the question/answer that lead to my code being like that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766417/save-changes-in-linq-to-sql/3770482#3770482

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSubstitute does not have direct support for arg matching ref parameters, but in general it will work with them ok.

I'm going to assume you have to use `ref` as stated in your question, but obviously if you can avoid `ref` your API will be simpler, as will testing it (irrespective of the frameworks you use).

In answer to your immediate question, you can pass a ref by updating your second code sample to:

```
form.SetItem(ref item);
```

For your side note, make sure you are not trying to push too much behaviour into your substitute. I've found that whenever I do this it is a sign I need to simplify the communication between the class I'm testing and its dependencies. (Or if I really need a lot of logic in a fake object, I'll hand code one rather than generate it; it can often be simpler.)

There are a few ways to get this call to throw an exception:

```
form.When(x => x.SetItem(ref item)).Do(x => { throw new ArgumentNullException(); });
```

This will throw an exception only when called with a null ref. You can also selectively add this behaviour depending on the argument passed, although I'd advise against this as it is probably a sign you are pushing too much into your substitute.

```
form.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.SetItem(ref item))
    .Do(x => {
        if (x[0] == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
    });
```

Finally, if you just want to check that the class you are testing responds properly when IAddAddressForm throws an arg null exception, I'd probably just do this:

```
form
    .WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.SetItem(ref item))
    .Do(x => { throw new ArgumentNullException(); });
```

That way you don't really care what the argument is, you just want to make sure the code you are testing reacts to this case properly.

Hope this helps.

*SIDE NOTE:*

If you want to use an arg matcher (like `Arg.Any<AddressItem>()`) for an `out` or `ref` argument you'll need to define it outside the call itself (this can be a tad error prone: you'll need to make sure you define the matchers in the same order as they'll go into the call):

```
        IAddAddressForm form = Substitute.For<IAddAddressForm>();
        AddressItem item = Arg.Is<AddressItem>(y => y.Number == 14);
        form
            .When(x => x.SetItem(ref item))
            .Do(x => { throw new ArgumentNullException(); });
        var address = new AddressItem { Number = 14 };
        form.SetItem(ref address);
```

Comment: Very complete answer!  Thanks a bunch.  It may look like I am doing to much in my substitutes, but that is because I am doing a training for my co-workers and my examples are all a bit contrived.